Why do PUT requests timeout when GET requests don't
When using the python requests library, and specifying a timeout, GET requests do not timeout when the total time to process the requests takes longer than the timeout, but PUT requests do.
python version: 3.8.10
requests version: 2.32.3
example code:
start = datetime.now()
requests.get(URL_WITH_1GB_FILE, params=None, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}, timeout=(1,1), verify=cert)
print(f"GET: {datetime.now()-start}")

even though the entire request takes over 60s to complete, we don't get a timeout. This I believe is expected behaviour, as individual packets are being received within the 1s timeout.
However, when trying to perform the same operation with a PUT request, the request times out, unless the connection timeout is greater than the time it takes for the entire PUT request to complete.
example code:
with open(PATH_TO_1GB_FILE ,"rb" ) as f:
    dat = f.read()
    timeouts = (100, 1) # connect, read
    start = datetime.now()
    requests.put(f"{local}/puttest", params=None, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}, timeout=timeouts, data=dat, verify=cert)
    print(f"PUT: {datetime.now()-start}")

with 100s connect timeout, this succeeds as the upload takes about 60s, however if the connect timeout is set to 10s, then this upload fails.
I am uploading 100MB files on 1mbps connections, which would require a 13min timeout, however I want the timeout to trigger much earlier if the internet connection is dropped.
I know I could achieve this by sending smaller chunks, instead of a full 100MB file, but was curious if there is a way for the timeouts to better handle this situation.

maybe set a higher read timeout? (the second timeout tuple item)

@eternal_white the read timeout does not seem to be the issue here. For the PUT command, if the connect timeout is less than the total request time I get a timeout, if it is greater, I don't get a timeout. The same behaviour is observed regardless of whether the read timeout is 1 or 100s.

The connect timeout is the max time spent before a connection is established (and essentially before the upload can start). The read timeout is the max time spent before a response can be read from the server, but if the server essentially does not respond before it has all of the chunks of the file, this is effectively the time between starting sending the first chunk and receiving confirmation of the last chunk, which is basically all of the upload time.

@GarethC Isn't the read time here also the same time between uploading chunks of data? connection timeout is understood, but I think the problem relays on logic behind the interaction between the server's response and your chunked data. Doesn't increasing read timeout (which in this case should be the time between sending a chunk and the server's acknowledgement) to a very high number solve the problem? Maybe you could just open  session between you and the server instead of a single put request?

@Grismar that was my understanding as well, but in practice adjusting the read timeout doesn't affect anything, I can leave it at 1 and never timeout. However adjusting the connection timeout is what results in issues.

@eternal_white my main issue is that I have put requests that can take up to 13min, so I would need to set a timeout greater than that, but if the internet connection drops after 1min, I want the request to timeout within a minute of that, not wait another 10+ min before the timeout occurs.

@GarethC then in this scenario I don't think it'd be practical to upload that file via this PUT request, unless that's the only way you could do so. Or you could make the program keep retrying until the file has been uploaded successfully

@GarethC Do you own the server or the service that you're trying to upload to? If you don't, check out what other methods of upload files they have. If you do, make an endpoint that opens a http session to receive the file in chunks. You could ask chatGPT to write one for you

@eternal_white in this instance I don't have much control, I need to use the PUT method, and can't make changes to the server code.
I'm not interested in retries, I just want the code to timeout when the internet connection drops, but doesn't timeout when it's just processing a very large file.

I seem to have come to a solution to my problem, but it doesn't quite align with my understanding of the timeouts.
Desired goal is that when the internet connection drops, the request should timeout, but I don't want it to timeout if the entire request is taking a long time, because I'm sending a lot of data on a slow connection.
In practice I can achieve this with PUT requests by specifying the connection timeout to be a very long time (or None), and have the read timeout be something reasonable.
with open(PATH_TO_1GB_FILE ,"rb" ) as f:
    dat = f.read()
    timeouts = (None, 60) # connect, read
    start = datetime.now()
    requests.put(f"{local}/puttest", params=None, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}, timeout=timeouts, data=dat, verify=cert)
    print(f"PUT: {datetime.now()-start}")

This code allows for the entire request to take an indefinite time, but if the internet connection is lost, will timeout within a minute.
